# Why listen for 401 errors when refreshing JWT and not checking expired state BEFORE sending the request?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

All the tutorials about refreshing JWT with Angular shows that I should listen to 401 status after sending the request with expired token. Curious why not to check token expired status on client BEFORE sending the request that certainly will be rejected? Are there any drawbacks? Can't find anything.

```js
        const authToken = this.authService.getToken() as string;

        if (authToken) {
            const isExpired = this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(authToken);

            console.log(isExpired && !this.isRefreshing);

            if (isExpired && !this.isRefreshing) {
                this.isRefreshing = true;
                this.authService.refreshToken().subscribe(response => {
                    this.isRefreshing = false;

                    this.authService.storeTokens(response.data.token, response.data.refreshToken);

                    return next.handle(this.addTokenToRequest(request, response.data.token));
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: How would you check whether the token has expired? There's no guarantee that the token won't expire before you think it does - there are other reasons other than time to consider.

Comment: Good point. I didn't thought about it because in my case client/server time will always be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if the date of the users computer does not match the server? They could still have a valid JWT but the client doesn't think they do and be held in limbo unable to refresh their token.

You should be validating the JWT on the server side where your code is protected from modification. You can too easily modify client side cookies / storage / javascript code.

Having the user bounce of the server is the most maintainable implementation because you are consolidating the expiry in a single place. There are many types of requests that can hit a server, not just ones that originate from your Angular app. i.e. someone using Postman and their user credentials to make api requests would evade any logic you put into the Angular app (obviously).

Comment: Yeah, just came to this. Didn't thought about client/server time difference because it's not my case. Thank you for your answer.